# base64 string gets written as an invalid image using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

I have the following code:

```
var __dirname = '/home/ubuntu/Site/public/uploads/';
var base64Data = '/9j/2wBDABAICAgICBAICAgQEBAQECAYEBAQECggIBggMCgwMDAoMDAwOEhAMDhIODAwQFhASFBQUFBQMEBYYFhQYEhQUFD/2wBDARAQEBAQECgYGChQODA4UFBQUFBQUFBQUA==UFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUP/AABEIADwAUAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQ==AwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eA==eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAw==BAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWVw==WFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQ==AxEAPwDmraLzIyTzkYINUby+njmEKtxH1HqeamkvXs7cxoPnPHPas4lyxZsknrUpGjZNJGsn7+2/4EvcUscjKMMKhViDkZqZJJnXaQSPcUwTAznOAKka2cJukxuPY06C3ELedA==oII+6PepA0074EW0E5x/n8qENu5Hb2zn5RkcGmeQ7zbCCMHmtKKMxuFHPBAPv6/zpJIgX4x+P+f85HpTTFYksFEafLxgdv8AP+fwp5k/doxYfLxz7f5J/P1pbYbUbn8cf59/1g==oYpMxMgP3T1/l/LNMogmt4rsHHUn+p/+tVY6W45DZHfj/PvU43xNkHIB/wA/y/WrEFwrDa/p/TH9Ki5NrlEWnlnLLx/F7f55/Kp7dEbnAwf8/wBTWi1vFOPl55/r/wDX/Wqktg==zQsWA6/eGev+fmoHYfbLHLHiQAsDwD74/wDZiPwBpXRcAx5x/D/T8hg/U1HauXmZF6nt/tf/AK2/SppkJTbGPvfd+nX+QX86ABVV2Mijj7q+4/8Arnim4+bcT+J/n/n1PpU6wA==dm0L7Y/p+v8A49TTCVO4n8f1z/X8TQMVflU9vr/n2x+HvWdJI8E5ZD9Rj/Pt+dX3YKMAdPX/AD+FULv7xYVQE5iOOR/niozCycjt/n+lS22oW8y4Zh0/oP8ACrIiikPB7/1NQA==FWG4kh4z/n/IFXkmiuVKsoOT3Hvj+oqBrX5dw9M/oDUW2WE/Ken/ANf/AAoAnayAkE9vJg+/Uf49f19qvaZZG/Mrx4jaJARHI3Xnt+QH4VRS5BHJ9v5/4ile7bAuIcEo3KH+JQ==PUfy/M0ATyh4hg8jGAPUf/q4+v0qB5SwLMR/j/n/ANmqeS8jZN5YYI6/1/kfxNZ9zdITiPgUDCabPGaqyupB5FJLN71VmmJ71SAhjWVT8oNXrO8uoiMgkA1TYlD8pNPjkc8ZpA==QjTXU224x2x+hFObUVY/Mnf+v/16zS7DvTSzY60Fl57xRjDAdP6f4U2K8BDKH49/pWc8jZojkbJ5osFy1Nc+SxMTkgnlaYb3PIFMVRK3zGnyWsUZUjPLYOTTsK5G1wzUxydhNQ==NNDHGDtFRFR5LH0xTE2f/9k=';
var buffer = new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + 'zorro.jpg', buffer, 0, buffer.length);
```

However the saved image is corrupt and won't open in Finder. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some header? The base64 string opens perfectly fine as inline data with an img tag.

EDIT: this works in HTML for me:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/2wBDABAICAgICBAICAgQEBAQECAYEBAQECggIBggMCgwMDAoMDAwOEhAMDhIODAwQFhASFBQUFBQMEBYYFhQYEhQUFD/2wBDARAQEBAQECgYGChQODA4UFBQUFBQUFBQUA==UFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUP/AABEIADwAUAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQ==AwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eA==eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAw==BAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWVw==WFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQ==AxEAPwDmraLzIyTzkYINUby+njmEKtxH1HqeamkvXs7cxoPnPHPas4lyxZsknrUpGjZNJGsn7+2/4EvcUscjKMMKhViDkZqZJJnXaQSPcUwTAznOAKka2cJukxuPY06C3ELedA==oII+6PepA0074EW0E5x/n8qENu5Hb2zn5RkcGmeQ7zbCCMHmtKKMxuFHPBAPv6/zpJIgX4x+P+f85HpTTFYksFEafLxgdv8AP+fwp5k/doxYfLxz7f5J/P1pbYbUbn8cf59/1g==oYpMxMgP3T1/l/LNMogmt4rsHHUn+p/+tVY6W45DZHfj/PvU43xNkHIB/wA/y/WrEFwrDa/p/TH9Ki5NrlEWnlnLLx/F7f55/Kp7dEbnAwf8/wBTWi1vFOPl55/r/wDX/Wqktg==zQsWA6/eGev+fmoHYfbLHLHiQAsDwD74/wDZiPwBpXRcAx5x/D/T8hg/U1HauXmZF6nt/tf/AK2/SppkJTbGPvfd+nX+QX86ABVV2Mijj7q+4/8Arnim4+bcT+J/n/n1PpU6wA==dm0L7Y/p+v8A49TTCVO4n8f1z/X8TQMVflU9vr/n2x+HvWdJI8E5ZD9Rj/Pt+dX3YKMAdPX/AD+FULv7xYVQE5iOOR/niozCycjt/n+lS22oW8y4Zh0/oP8ACrIiikPB7/1NQA==FWG4kh4z/n/IFXkmiuVKsoOT3Hvj+oqBrX5dw9M/oDUW2WE/Ken/ANf/AAoAnayAkE9vJg+/Uf49f19qvaZZG/Mrx4jaJARHI3Xnt+QH4VRS5BHJ9v5/4ile7bAuIcEo3KH+JQ==PUfy/M0ATyh4hg8jGAPUf/q4+v0qB5SwLMR/j/n/ANmqeS8jZN5YYI6/1/kfxNZ9zdITiPgUDCabPGaqyupB5FJLN71VmmJ71SAhjWVT8oNXrO8uoiMgkA1TYlD8pNPjkc8ZpA==QjTXU224x2x+hFObUVY/Mnf+v/16zS7DvTSzY60Fl57xRjDAdP6f4U2K8BDKH49/pWc8jZojkbJ5osFy1Nc+SxMTkgnlaYb3PIFMVRK3zGnyWsUZUjPLYOTTsK5G1wzUxydhNQ==NNDHGDtFRFR5LH0xTE2f/9k="/>
```

Comment: Can you try to open the result image with a simple text editor? Maybe you are simply writing the base64 directly into zorro.jpg?

Comment: Are you sure the base64 string is correct? I can't seem to get it to display in any way. Do you have a working fiddle, maybe?

Comment: You have not one base64 string there, but 15 (all ending in '==', except for the last one). Export the data as a single base64 string and everything will be fine

Comment: The base64 string is correct. You can check with `echo -n "/9j/2wBD..." | base64 -d > image`. This is one big image base64 encoded.

Comment: What is the inline image URL you are using that is working? That string is not valid `base64` because it contains `=` in the data, which is not allowed. `=` is only used as a padding character at the end of the data in base64.

Comment: I added the IMG tag test I was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-encoded your string into proper base64

```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==
```

As to why the base64 encoded data is working on my end, the [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-3.3) for base64 states this:

> Furthermore, such specifications MAY ignore the pad    character, "=",
> treating it as non-alphabet data, if it is present    before the end
> of the encoded data.  If more than the allowed number    of pad
> characters is found at the end of the string (e.g., a base 64
> string terminated with "==="), the excess pad characters MAY also be
> ignored.

Some implementation will ignore the added "=" and some will not.

EDIT:
As other has pointed out, your base64 string seems to be many base64 string concatenated together. Here is your string:

```
/9j/2wBDABAICAgICBAICAgQEBAQECAYEBAQECggIBggMCgwMDAoMDAwOEhAMDhIODAwQFhASFBQUFBQMEBYYFhQYEhQUFD/2wBDARAQEBAQECgYGChQODA4UFBQUFBQUFBQUA==
UFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUP/AABEIADwAUAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQ==
AwMCBAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYnKCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eA==
eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAw==
BAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWVw==
WFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQ==
AxEAPwDmraLzIyTzkYINUby+njmEKtxH1HqeamkvXs7cxoPnPHPas4lyxZsknrUpGjZNJGsn7+2/4EvcUscjKMMKhViDkZqZJJnXaQSPcUwTAznOAKka2cJukxuPY06C3ELedA==
oII+6PepA0074EW0E5x/n8qENu5Hb2zn5RkcGmeQ7zbCCMHmtKKMxuFHPBAPv6/zpJIgX4x+P+f85HpTTFYksFEafLxgdv8AP+fwp5k/doxYfLxz7f5J/P1pbYbUbn8cf59/1g==
oYpMxMgP3T1/l/LNMogmt4rsHHUn+p/+tVY6W45DZHfj/PvU43xNkHIB/wA/y/WrEFwrDa/p/TH9Ki5NrlEWnlnLLx/F7f55/Kp7dEbnAwf8/wBTWi1vFOPl55/r/wDX/Wqktg==
zQsWA6/eGev+fmoHYfbLHLHiQAsDwD74/wDZiPwBpXRcAx5x/D/T8hg/U1HauXmZF6nt/tf/AK2/SppkJTbGPvfd+nX+QX86ABVV2Mijj7q+4/8Arnim4+bcT+J/n/n1PpU6wA==
dm0L7Y/p+v8A49TTCVO4n8f1z/X8TQMVflU9vr/n2x+HvWdJI8E5ZD9Rj/Pt+dX3YKMAdPX/AD+FULv7xYVQE5iOOR/niozCycjt/n+lS22oW8y4Zh0/oP8ACrIiikPB7/1NQA==
FWG4kh4z/n/IFXkmiuVKsoOT3Hvj+oqBrX5dw9M/oDUW2WE/Ken/ANf/AAoAnayAkE9vJg+/Uf49f19qvaZZG/Mrx4jaJARHI3Xnt+QH4VRS5BHJ9v5/4ile7bAuIcEo3KH+JQ==
PUfy/M0ATyh4hg8jGAPUf/q4+v0qB5SwLMR/j/n/ANmqeS8jZN5YYI6/1/kfxNZ9zdITiPgUDCabPGaqyupB5FJLN71VmmJ71SAhjWVT8oNXrO8uoiMgkA1TYlD8pNPjkc8ZpA==
QjTXU224x2x+hFObUVY/Mnf+v/16zS7DvTSzY60Fl57xRjDAdP6f4U2K8BDKH49/pWc8jZojkbJ5osFy1Nc+SxMTkgnlaYb3PIFMVRK3zGnyWsUZUjPLYOTTsK5G1wzUxydhNQ==
NNDHGDtFRFR5LH0xTE2f/9k=
```

Notice how each of base64 string are 136 chracter long. If you decoded each of these base64 and append the result of each decoded base64 into a file, you will get your image.

Comment: And how exactly did you reencode this? I get this base64 string from a third party and it's easier to fix it on my part then to get them to change it.

Comment: @BramVandewalle I decoded the base64 you provided, I checked that I could open the file properly and re-encoded the file into proper base64. 

I think that just decoding/re-encoding would work. But I think your problem is the base64 decoder you use which is unable to handle '==' in the base64 string.

Comment: @BramVandewalle Can you confirm that it works with the base64 I provided to you?

Comment: it does work, but I don't understand how I can fix it using the Node.JS fs library.

Comment: If it does not work, it means that the js library that decodes base64 is strict about the padding character. You could do a shellcommand to `echo -n BASE64STRING | base64 -d` if you are on a linux box.

Comment: Thanks, I had to decode each part of the string separately like you said.